# mysql special characters - incorrect string value '\xE1n'

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation

We are running a cron script which takes new users from a csv and inserts them into our database. It is failing whenever it comes across a user with a special character in their name, but I can't see why, as far as I can see everything is set so that it should work.

Here is an example of a name it's failing on:

```
Siobhán
```

Error message:

```
!! Incorrect string value: '\xE1n' for column 'firstname' at row 1
```

And then the var_dump of the data it's trying to insert has the name as: `Siobh` so it's cut off the special characters

Here is the output of show variables like 'char%' on our database:

```
character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database utf8
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server utf8
character_set_system utf8
character_sets_dir /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

The collation of the users table is `utf8_unicode_ci`

The collation of the firstname and lastname columns is `utf8_unicode_ci`

The header of the php script sets:

```
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

And when I run `mb_detect_encoding()` on the variable before it's passed into the query, it comes back as `UTF-8`

So I am out of ideas here as to why it's failing...

Does anyone have any ideas as to where we are going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you save the CSV as UTF-8 ?

Comment: The csv is generated automatically by a script from another dept. Is there anyway to check?

Comment: Open with your text editor. Notepad++ fits my needs. Make sure your other scripts are saved as utf-8, too and all the data you copy is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: Hi, This script runs automatically every night, so it's not something we can go in manually each time and save the file in a different encoding, if that's what you meant. When I open the csv in notepad++ the Encoding has ANSI selected, but that's top of the list so it might just be a default. If i switch that to utf8, the name changes in notepad++ to `SiobhxE1n` where the `xE1` is highlighted black as a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we already found the problem in the comments, here is the solution:

The program creating your csv file, does create the file in ANSI format.
It needs to write in UTF-8.

This implies that the actual source of the data iself needs to be UTF-8, too and all your PHP files should be UTF-8, too.

See this for help: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php#104325

Wherever your scripts takes the data from and into the csv, the data must be converted or already be in utf-8.